# JPA entity with nested one-to-many entity with the help of Hibernate. Easy way to sort by one of the nested entity's attributes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Basically I have something similar to this:

```
public class Object {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "object", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKey(name = "lang")
  private Map<String, NestedObject> nestedObjects = new HashMap<String, NestedObject>();
}

public class NestedObject {

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID")
  private Object object;

  @Column(name = "lang", nullable = false)
  private String lang;

  @Column(name = "attr", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
  private String attr;
}
```

I can easily request paginated list of Objects sorted by one of it's primary attributes using the sort url property thanks to spring, but in this particular case I need it sorted by the attr attribute in NestedObject. I couldn't find any simple way to manage this, but there might have been something I missed. I would appreciate any help that would point me in the right direction.

Comment: I've see this exact question asked already, and you still haven't clarified. An Object has MANY nested objects. So it has MANY attr. So you can't sort by attr: every objects have many of them. What do you want to achieve. Give a concrete example.